# bootloop in Ulefone Armor 8 pro

Tags: rooting, unbricking

I've installed successfully TWRP recovery, but after installing Magick, in order to root it, I have a bootloop, with this message:

> Your device has been unlocked and can’t be trusted.
> Your device will boot in 5 seconds​

I cannot enter recovery mode any more.
Only I can enter in fastboot mode, and issue fastboot commands.

I've tried to restore the recovery partition with the original one:

```
fastboot flash boot recovery.img
```

but even though the flashing terminates with success, I cannot access recovery.

I've downloaded the stock ROM for my Armor 8 Pro, but the SPMultiPortDownloadProject doesn't recognize my phone, when I hit the Scan button. It does recognize the scatter file from the stock ROM.

[image: SPMultiPortDownloadProject]

I've tried unsuccessfully other tools like mtpclient, and SP Flash Tool.
[image: SP Flash tool]

The solutions here don't help, as my phone isn't recognized:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/armor-7-ulefone-twrp-and-roms.4116603/

The phone uses MediaTek chipset (MT6771 Helio P60 (12 nm)), and I've installed the MediaTek USB VCOM drivers.

[Specs of the phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/ulefone_armor_8_pro-10898.php)

**UPDATE**:
I'm using Linux and Windows 10 in Virtual Box.  I've made accesible the USB device to VirtualBox.

Only when activating `fastboot`, I can see the device with the `lsusb` utility in Linux.

When trying to switch on the phone, also there is a 2 or 3 second period of USB port visibility, but this isn't enough.

```
Bus 003 Device 028: ID 0e8d:201c MediaTek Inc. Android
```

Additional info I've found useful:

- [Similar case](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bricked-ulefone-armor-8-pro.4390047/)
- [How to unbrick with the SP tool](https://www.droidwin.com/unbrick-mediatek-sp-flash-tool/?unapproved=5628&moderation-hash=8f4438f58b7b555da17d41678c20bdd1#comment-5628)
- [SP Flash tool](https://spflashtools.com/)

Comment: The message is just a warning that the bootloader is unlocked. Afterwards it should continue to boot. I am not familiar with that device or MTK devices but modern phone use a secure boot and as you have modified the kernel image (by Magisk) the boot verification fails. Usually you can fix this by disable DM Verity.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for your explanation.  How can I disable DM Verify?
What I can do is to use the `fastboot` tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this solution, but I've sent it to external repair service.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).